# Problem with multiple ISAPI Extensions processing the same request (Exchange 2003)

Tags: iis, isapi, exchange-server-2003, isapi-extension

I am trying to add an ISAPI extension that would read the request content before it goes on to the original extension that processes the request.

To be more specific, I added my ISAPI extension in the Exchange 2003 ActiveSync folder (more details about it later) above Microsoft's original "massync.dll" which processes the ActiveSync requests.

Deployment:
1. Under IIS Manager-->Web Service Extensions, I added my extension and set it as "Allowed"
2. Under IIS Manager-->Web Sites-->Default Web Site-->Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync-->Properties-->Virtual Directory-->Application settings-->Configuration, I inserted my extension above the original "massync.dll"

On HttpExtensionProc(), my extension returns HSE_STATUS_SUCCESS.

The problem is that my extension catches the request successfully and I am able to read its content.
However, with my extension, the request does not proceed to the next extension and the ActiveSync process fails.

How do I make the request proceed to the next extension with my extension installed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to install as a wildcard script map and call [HSE_REQ_EXEC_URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525925%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).